# Is it necessary to learn TypeScript first before going to explore Angular2?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

Is it necessary to learn TypeScript first before attempting to learn AngularJS 2?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not necessary to learn TypeScript but I would definitely recommend that you do learn it.  TypeScript is excellent. Not only that, but TypeScript is actually great and very solid

Check this [answer](https://www.quora.com/AngularJS/Is-it-necessary-to-learn-TypeScript-first-before-attempting-to-learn-Angular-2)

Answer (score 0):

> The official stance of the AngularJS team is that it will be
>   completely optional. You could write your whole application in the
>   JavaScript we know today (ECMAscript5).  But to be honest, there are
>   some serious issues with that version.
>
> - no real classes and inheritance (only prototype)
> - no type checking
> - no module system (loading parts of javascript)
>
> If you still want to write it in ECMAscript, you'll have to write more
>   code to do the same,  and ergo have a higher chance at bugs getting
>   into your code.
>
> You could write it in ECMAscript 6, which is the next version.
>   Unfortunately it's not supported yet in most browsers. But you can
>   already use it,  and then compile your code to ECMAscript 5 during the
>   deploy fase (you can setup GRUNT to do this)
>
> Finally you could use Typescript. It offers everything ECMAscript
>   offers and more. Learning it should not feel like learning a new
>   language, since JavaScript is also valid in Typescript. They just
>   added some syntactical sugar to make it more powerful and useful. You
>   will still have to compile it to ECMAscript 5 during deploy.
>
> Via - [Bert Verhelst | Quora Discussions](https://www.quora.com/AngularJS/Is-it-necessary-to-learn-TypeScript-first-before-attempting-to-learn-Angular-2)

Comment: I'd probably give credit to the person you copied this word for word from: Bert Verhelst from the comments [here](https://www.quora.com/AngularJS/Is-it-necessary-to-learn-TypeScript-first-before-attempting-to-learn-Angular-2)

Comment: @GregVanGorp yes we should give the credit to the person. That's why the link is mentioned in the answer