# Is Typescript mandatory for running Angular?

Tags: angular, angular5

I am trying to understand that can we code in Angular with Typescript. Is Typescript mandatory? Besides Typescript, is there any other way to use Angular 2+ framework?

Comment: duplicate Question see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33329559/is-it-necessary-to-learn-typescript-first-before-going-to-explore-angular2

Comment: I am not asking about learning Typescript before exploring Angular. My question is for Angular framework is typescript mandatory?

Comment: :) yes ofcourse

Comment: @Krishna that question is answered there. Typescript is optional, but strongly recommended.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it necessary to learn TypeScript first before going to explore Angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33329559/is-it-necessary-to-learn-typescript-first-before-going-to-explore-angular2)

Comment: Angular framework is completely with typescript only right?  then why do you want to omit the typescript.

Comment: typescript is just javascript. with a little error checking built in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Angular is a TypeScript framework. Built in TypeScript, and compiling TypeScript code to work.

To be exactly, you will use:

1. HTML (View)
2. CSS (style)
3. JavaScript (Usually used in the index.html to use external libraries CDN)
4. TypeScript (Components, Services, etc...)